# Finding unique combinations of tuples

Tags: python-3.x

```
Input: 1 2 3 4
Output: (1,2)(3,4)
(1,3)(2,4)
(1,4)(2,3)
```

I have been able to come up with a solution for the problem but it is efficient. It needs to be optimized.

```
comb = combinations(Arr,int(n/2))
l = []
for i in comb:
    l.append(i)
final_comb = combinations(l,int(n/2))
for i in final_comb:
    if is_unique(n,i):
       print(i)

def is_unique(n,tup):
    k = []
    for i in tup:
        for j in i:
            k.append(j)
    if len(set(k)) == n:
        return True
    return False
```

The output must be combinations of tuples such that they all have the numbers given as input

Comment: When you use imported packages, include the import statement in the code.  You've also left out `Arr` and `n`.  What are those values, exactly?

Answer (score 2):

- Use [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html)

```
from itertools import combinations

list(combinations([1, 2, 3, 4], 2))

>>> [(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 3), (2, 4), (3, 4)]
```

Comment: from the output u have got u need to select the tuples in such a way it has all the digits in the input
Final output:
(1,2)(3,4) or
(1,3)(2,4) or
(1,4)(2,3)

Comment: You should update the question.  It seems your actual question is **How do I order the combinations, based upon the given input order?**